# Couthpotato no longer starting

Tags: couchpotato

Running CouchPotato on a Synology NAS, and I believe CouchPotato recently tried to auto-update itself, because it suddenly stopped working. I tried [the solution recommended here](https://github.com/RuudBurger/CouchPotatoServer/issues/1532#issuecomment-16357229), but that doesn't work. Judging from the logs, it looks like some SQL update is trying to run but it returns an error:

```
07:09:56 CRITICAL [                 __main__] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/couchpotatoserver/share/CouchPotatoServer/CouchPotato.py", line 128, in <module>
l.run()
  File "/usr/local/couchpotatoserver/share/CouchPotatoServer/CouchPotato.py", line 83, in run
runCouchPotato(self.options, base_path, sys.argv[1:], data_dir = self.data_dir, log_dir = self.log_dir, Env = Env)
  File "/volume1/@appstore/couchpotatoserver/share/CouchPotatoServer/couchpotato/runner.py", line 207, in runCouchPotato
upgrade(db, repo)
  File "/usr/local/couchpotatoserver/share/CouchPotatoServer/libs/migrate/versioning/api.py", line 186, in upgrade
return _migrate(url, repository, version, upgrade=True, err=err, **opts)
  File "<string>", line 2, in _migrate
  File "/usr/local/couchpotatoserver/share/CouchPotatoServer/libs/migrate/versioning/util/__init__.py", line 159, in with_engine
return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/couchpotatoserver/share/CouchPotatoServer/libs/migrate/versioning/api.py", line 366, in _migrate
schema.runchange(ver, change, changeset.step)
  File "/usr/local/couchpotatoserver/share/CouchPotatoServer/libs/migrate/versioning/schema.py", line 91, in runchange
change.run(self.engine, step)
  File "/usr/local/couchpotatoserver/share/CouchPotatoServer/libs/migrate/versioning/script/py.py", line 145, in run
script_func(engine)
  File "/usr/local/couchpotatoserver/share/CouchPotatoServer/couchpotato/core/migration/versions/001_Releases_last_edit.py", line 15, in upgrade
create_column(last_edit_column, release)
  File "/usr/local/couchpotatoserver/share/CouchPotatoServer/libs/migrate/changeset/schema.py", line 38, in create_column
return table.create_column(column, *p, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/couchpotatoserver/share/CouchPotatoServer/libs/migrate/changeset/schema.py", line 426, in create_column
column.create(table=self, *p, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/couchpotatoserver/share/CouchPotatoServer/libs/migrate/changeset/schema.py", line 528, in create
engine._run_visitor(visitorcallable, self, connection, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/couchpotatoserver/share/CouchPotatoServer/libs/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2302, in _run_visitor
conn._run_visitor(visitorcallable, element, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/couchpotatoserver/share/CouchPotatoServer/libs/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1972, in _run_visitor
**kwargs).traverse_single(element)
  File "/usr/local/couchpotatoserver/share/CouchPotatoServer/libs/migrate/changeset/ansisql.py", line 53, in traverse_single
ret = super(AlterTableVisitor, self).traverse_single(elem)
  File "/usr/local/couchpotatoserver/share/CouchPotatoServer/libs/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 106, in traverse_single
return meth(obj, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/couchpotatoserver/share/CouchPotatoServer/libs/migrate/changeset/databases/sqlite.py", line 75, in visit_column
super(SQLiteColumnGenerator,self).visit_column(column)
  File "/usr/local/couchpotatoserver/share/CouchPotatoServer/libs/migrate/changeset/ansisql.py", line 101, in visit_column
self.execute()
  File "/usr/local/couchpotatoserver/share/CouchPotatoServer/libs/migrate/changeset/ansisql.py", line 42, in execute
return self.connection.execute(self.buffer.getvalue())
  File "/usr/local/couchpotatoserver/share/CouchPotatoServer/libs/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1449, in execute
params)
  File "/usr/local/couchpotatoserver/share/CouchPotatoServer/libs/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1628, in _execute_text
statement, parameters
  File "/usr/local/couchpotatoserver/share/CouchPotatoServer/libs/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1698, in _execute_context
context)
  File "/usr/local/couchpotatoserver/share/CouchPotatoServer/libs/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1691, in _execute_context
context)
  File "/usr/local/couchpotatoserver/share/CouchPotatoServer/libs/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 331, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
OperationalError: (OperationalError) duplicate column name: last_edit '\nALTER TABLE release ADD last_edit INTEGER' ()
```

The last line seems to be the key, ie. the error "duplicate column name: last_edit '\nALTER TABLE release ADD last_edit INTEGER' ()".

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution I ended up with was to uninstall it, then install custom CouchPotato package specifying the RuudBurger repo [as described here](https://couchpota.to/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2043&start=20). If you don't use the RuudBurger repo, then you get the french CouchPotato.